# Using Mockito & Guice to test interfaces with generics in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, guice

I am new to Scala, and I'm running into this problem when I'm trying to unit test some of my interfaces.

I have an InputService trait with method

```
def poll(parameters: HashMap[String, String]): Option[T]
```

where T is generic, so InputService has a type parameter [T].

In my module, I have

```
val inputService: InputService[String] = mock(classOf[InputService[String]])
bind[InputService[String]].toInstance(inputService)
```

and in my InputServiceTest, I have

```
  var inputService: InputService[String] = _
  before {
    inputService = Guice.createInjector(new MockWatcherModule).getInstance(classOf[InputService[String]])
  }
```

But the issue is when I run it, it gives me this error

```
Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - Guice configuration errors:
1) No implementation for services.InputService was bound.
  while locating services.InputService
```

I think it's because it's looking for services.InputService to bound, but it only has services.InputService[String]. However, when I just use InputService instead of InputService[String], I get the error `Trait missing Type Parameter`.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Turns out that I can use typeLiteral from scala-guice and KeyExtensions to solve my issue. Thanks Tavian!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to type erasure, in the `getInstance(classOf[InputService[String]])` call, you're just passing `InputService.class`.  You need to pass a `TypeLiteral` instead to encode the generic type information.  From a quick Google it looks like

```scala
import net.codingwell.scalaguice._
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.InjectorExtensions._

Guice.createInjector(new MockWatcherModule).instance[InputService[String]]
```

will work.

Comment: How exactly do I use the type literal?
I created a variable `var typeLiteral = new TypeLiteral[InputService[String]]`, and what goes in to the getInstance?

Comment: scala-guice [provides](https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice/blob/a19861ad7ce2c0c1ff05645d01e48694ed344c35/src/main/scala/net/codingwell/package.scala#L34) a function `typeLiteral` that makes one for you.  You can use it exactly as written in my answer.

Comment: If you want to make your own, you'll have to write `var typeLiteral = new TypeLiteral[InputService[String]] {};` (note the `{}`), and pass that to `getInstance()`.

Comment: Thanks Tavian, but typeLiteral is of type TypeLiteral[InputService[String]] but getInstance expects a class. Am I doing something wrong syntactically?

Comment: Argh nope, I just forgot there's no `TypeLiteral` overload for `getInstance`.  There's one that takes a `Key` though, so you can do `getInstance(typeLiteral[InputService[String]].toKey)`.

Comment: Isn't there no toKey method for typeLiterals? typeLiteral returns TypeLiteral[T] which (just checked the docs) doesn't have a toKey method. :(

Comment: It's an [extension method](https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice/blob/master/src/main/scala/net/codingwell/scalaguice/KeyExtensions.scala#L25).  You can also do `Key.get(type literal here)`.

Comment: No problem.  I edited the answer with an even more convenient way.