# Issue with dependency injection using Play 2.5.x

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

Our application is built using **Play 2.5.10.** 
In one of our custom defined play modules , we bind a class to an object instance as below

```
import play.api.inject.{Binding, Module}
import scalax.collection.io.json.descriptor.predefined.Di
import scalax.collection.io.json.descriptor.{Descriptor, StringNodeDescriptor}

    class CustomModule extends Module {
          override def bindings(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration): Seq[Binding[_]] = {
            Seq(
              bind[HierarchyGraph[String]]
                .to[HierarchyGraphImpl],
              bind[Descriptor[String]]
                .toInstance(new Descriptor(StringNodeDescriptor,Di.descriptor[String]()))
            )
          }
        }
```

Our trait and its implemented class are defined as below :

```
    trait HierarchyGraph[T] {
      def toJson(graph : Graph[T, DiEdge]) : JsValue
    }

    class HierarchyGraphImpl @Inject()
    (descriptor: Descriptor[String]) extends HierarchyGraph[String] {

      def toJson(graph : Graph[String, DiEdge]) : JsValue = {
        val jsText = JsonGraph(graph).toJson(descriptor)
        try {
          Json.parse(jsText)
        } catch {
          case e : Exception => Json.toJson(Json.obj())
        }
      }

   }
```

But when we run the application , we encounter the below run time error

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in scalax.collection.io.json.descriptor.Descriptor. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at scalax.collection.io.json.descriptor.Descriptor.class(Descriptor.scala:58)
  while locating scalax.collection.io.json.descriptor.Descriptor<java.lang.String>
    for parameter 0 at schema.authorization.HierarchyGraphImpl.<init>(HierarchyGraph.scala:27)
  at modules.authorization.AuthorizationModule.bindings(AuthorizationModule.scala:19):
Binding(interface schema.authorization.HierarchyGraph to ConstructionTarget(class schema.authorization.HierarchyGraphImpl)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

1 error
```

Can some one help us out in resolving this error . We want to know where exactly are we going wrong with our bindings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Type erasure strikes again.  Here's an old answer of mine, hopefully it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31682877/502399

Comment: Hi @TavianBarnes , thanks for the reference , but instead of instanceOf , I would like to bind an object instance as :=> new Descriptor(StringNodeDescriptor,Di.descriptor[String]())

Comment: Looks like `play.api.inject.Modules` doesn't work with generic types. And it looks like your Play app uses Guice under the hood. In Guice you'd do it like `bind(new TypeLiteral[Descriptor[String]]{}).toInstance(new Descriptor(...))`. If you don't mind using Guice directly, explore this option. In any case you enable Guice modules in the config the same way you do it for Play modules.

Comment: Hi @TavianBarnes replacing play module with scala module from scala guice resolved the error . Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @yahor you were right play modules do not support generic types